# Cloud functions in Firebase trigger are not part of the transaction update

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am using the realtime database and I am using transactions to ensure the integrity of my data set. In my example below I am updating `currentTime` on every update.

```js
export const updateTime = functions.database.ref("/users/{userId}/projects/{projectId}")
    .onUpdate((snapshot) => {
      const beforeData = snapshot.before.val();
      const afterData = snapshot.after.val();
      if (beforeData.currentTime !== afterData.currentTime) {
        return Promise.resolve();
      } else {
        return snapshot.after.ref.update( {currentTime: new Date().getTime()})
            .catch((err) =>{
              console.error(err);
            });
      }
    });
```

It seems the cloud function is not part of the transaction, but triggers multiple updates in my clients, which I try to avoid.

For example, I watched this [starter tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DglTSNEdl0U) which replaces `:pizza:` with a pizza emoji. In my client I would see `:pizza:` for one frame before it gets replaced with the emoji. I know, the pizza tutorial is just an example, but I am running into a similar issue. Any advice is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Functions don't run as part of the database transaction indeed. They run after the database has been updated, and receive "before" and "after" snapshots of the affected data.

If you want a Cloud Function to serve as an approval process, the idiomatic approach is to have the clients write to a different location (typically called a pending queue) that the function listens to. The function then performs whatever operation it wants, and writes the result to the final location.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation! Just for clarification, you suggest to use something like `"/users/{userId}/projects/{projectId}_pending"` with an array of updates that the function then applies to the original `project`?

Comment: Yup, that's it.